# Short story of man who can throw objects with precision

Tags: story-identification

I believe I read it in the 80's in a short story collection.
Plot involves him throwing pieces of rock back into a wall and a dice game against the devil.

Comment: At first, I thought you were talking about the Matheson story, but that one's a carnival game.

Comment: This is [no fiction!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Bristow)

Answer (score 4):

[Gonna Roll the Bones by Fritz Leiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonna_Roll_the_Bones). See also [the info on the ifsdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41361).

The reference to throwing rocks back into the wall is:

> Joe Slattermill had been almost incredibly deft at precision throwing. In the mine he could carom a rock off a wall of ore to crack a rat’s skull fifty feet away in the dark and he sometimes amused himself by tossing little fragments of rock back into the holes from which they had fallen, so that they stuck there, perfectly fitted in, for at least a second.

He uses this throwing skill in a dice game, but ...

> It isn't really with the Devil!